# Convert a String of bits into an array of enums using java 8 streams

Tags: java, generics, java-8, enums, java-stream

I have a string of space separated bits (1's and 0's) that I want to convert to an array of enums. Below is my effort so far.

This is the Enum class

```
enum Color { RED, GREEN }
```

Here is the conversion code.

```
Color[] colors = (Color[]) Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().split("\\s"))
    .map(i -> {
         if (i.equals("0")) return Color.RED;
         else return Color.GREEN;
    })
    .toArray();
```

I am facing the following problems with this code:

1. It uses type casting to change from an array of `Object`s to an array of `Color`s which may create runtime errors. I would like it very much if there was no type casting.
2. The map function. I have searched here on StackOverflow on `mapToObj` to see if there is a way I can specify the return type of the map. I think it is safer when you specify that the map should return a `Color` object.

Comment: Very interesting! How do I specify it is a 0 or a 1

Comment: How do you specify *what* is a 0 or a 1?

Comment: Yes. How do I tell Color which one it is

Comment: With your map function, as you do currently?

Comment: Like this: `map(i -> i.toArray[i])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to go:

```
Color[] colors = Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().split("\\s"))
    .map(i -> i.equals("0") ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN)
    .toArray(Color[]::new);
```

If you want to convert a `Stream` to an object array, you need to use [`Stream::toArray(IntFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) method.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the casting, pass parameter to `toArray`:

```
.toArray(Color[]::new)
```

This is the only change required.

There is no need to specify a return type for the map function. The fact that you're returning only instances of `Color` means its return type is `Color`.

Comment: I think you should have kept the part about polyexpression. It was fascinating. And mind blowing

Comment: @GilbertS it wasn't actually correct, though. Method invocations aren't polyexpressions. The lambda and method reference are, just not the `Stream.map(...)` itself.

Comment: Okay, I don't understand what you just said, but I will research more. I know method references look like this: `Color[]::new`. But one thing I still can't figure out is why you said I should use: `.toArray(new Color[0])`. What is the 0 in the Color[] array. Is it always 0?

Comment: @GilbertS I got the API confused with `Collections.toArray`, which takes an array, rather than a method reference to construct a new instance of an array. The reason for zero is somewhat complicated (e.g. you could pass in a pre-sized array), but the current "best practice" is to use zero.

Comment: Ohh! The size. Gotcha. Although it doesn't work in practice. The IDE says: `reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) A exist so that Color[] conforms to IntFunction<A[]>`